# Retain Old and New Values in SQL Columns based on Current and Previous Row

Tags: sql-server-2012

This is how my table should look like:

MY requirement  is i have to add a new column called **ChangeType** that should be calculated based on the **Phasechange**.

If the first row phasechange is null it should be "Baseline".IF it has value then it should be phasechange.IN this example for RevisionNO=2 ,phasechange=1 then the changetype=phasechange as previous value for the RevisionNo=1 the phasechange was null.

Then for revisionno=3 ,phasechange=null so changeType should be again a phasechange.

Then for revisionno=4 ,phasechange= 3 so changeType should be again a phasechange (as for revisionno=3 it was null)

for revisionno in (5,6) phasechange =3 which is same as previos Revision(4) so the changetype should be baselined.

```
 ProjectID   DocumentNo   RevisionNo     PhaseChange      ChangeType

 102176-001     1             1              NULL         Baselined    

 102176-001     2             2               1           Phasechange     

 102176-001     3             3              NULL         Phasechange     

 102176-001     4             4               3           Phasechange     

 102176-001     5             5               3           Baselined     

 102176-001     6             6               3           Baselined
```

Example code:

```
Create table #temp(
ProjectID varchar(35),
Documentno int,
Revisionno int,
PhaseChange int,
ChangeType varchar(35))

insert into #temp values ( '102176-001',    1,  1,  NULL,NULL)

insert into #temp values ( '102176-001',    2,  2,  1,NULL)

insert into #temp values ( '102176-001',    3,  3,  NULL,NULL)

insert into #temp values ( '102176-001',    4,  4,  3,NULL) 

insert into #temp values ( '102176-001',    5,  5,  3,NULL)


insert into #temp values ( '102176-001',    6,  6,  3,NULL)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Why is there so much duplication in your data?

Comment: Sorry got duplicated while editing.Now the data is correct

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? ("SQL" is just  a query language, not a DBMS product)

Comment: Can somebody plz help  this needs to b completed ASAP.I'm stuck on this problem

Comment: It seems that `LAG` function would be useful here.